# Is there a way in spring to destroy a http session if another login attempt of a logged in user comes?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

For our application with spring-boot *(2.1.4)* it is important to us that a user can only be logged in once.

This was relatively easy to configure and works great in relation with REST requests.

```
http
  .sessionManagement()
  .maximumSessions(1)
  .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false)
  .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
```

Much of the communication runs through websockets, and getting here starts our problem.
The view of our browser app changes when the websocket connection is disconnected. On the server side the websocket handshake is disconnected if the http session is invalid.

As I understand it, if a user logs in again with an already logged in user, the http session remains valid until the next REST request. I would like the http session to terminate independently from requests.

I have a workaround where I check every `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` if there are already sessions of this user and terminate them. This approach works, but I don't like it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A relatively blind guess, but have you tried changing the `sessionFixation`? It should create a completely new session, without copying over old attributes, on an authentication attempt.

```
  http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation().newSession()
```

;

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after that I learned about `sessionFixation` and tested it. Unfortunately there is no improvement.